# Traversing an object model recursively to search for a value

Tags: powershell, recursion

I need to recursively traverse a very large and complicated object model to search for a particular value of an ID.

The value I'm looking for is in a property called "ID", but objects with a particular ID might have many children, some of which are arrays, each having a different ID, and each of those children in turn can have a different ID and so on and so forth.

[image]

So if I give you an object, say $web, and you know that deep down in it's object model there is a value of an object that you are looking for. How do you look for it using recursion and reflection?

Note: This is a generic powershell/recursion/programming question even though the topic is SharePoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `Format-Custom`? For example, getting a lot of nested member data from a directory info is done like so,

```
(gci)[0] | fc > test.txt
```

Will give some 8800 lines of data for expanded members.

Comment: I've tried that. It expands the members but it does not call "get" on the properties and their children and expand them recursively.

Comment: Actually, you are right. I was trying `$web | Format-Custom -Property ID -Depth 3`. I need to use `$web | Format-Custom -Depth 3` to have it traverse recursively. How do I then filter to show IDs only AND traverse recursively?